# How to set ExtJS window show/hide with animation?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Here is My sourcecode:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    id:'edit_segtype_win',
    title:'msg',
    layout: 'fit',
    html:data,
    modal:true,
    resizable:false,
    constrain:true
}).show(undefined,bind_ajax_success);
```

When i call show(...),the window will show without any animation.
I want to add some animation,such as fadein/fadeout/slidein/slideout.
Can somebody help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Anim object http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.fx.Anim to use in your Window Component like this:

```
var myWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    html:"hello world",
});

Ext.create('Ext.fx.Anim', {
    target: myWindow,
    duration: 1000,
    from: {
        width: 400, //starting width 400
        opacity: 0,       // Transparent
        color: '#ffffff', // White
        left: 0
    },
    to: {
        width: 300, //end width 300
        height: 300 // end height 300
    }
});
```

And then, that animation is added when your call to

```
window.show();
```

Comment: This solution seems to work only once and does not work on hide. Does anyone have suggestions or other examples of using Ext.fx.Anim with show/hide ?

Comment: Just nitpicking, but `width: 400` should be `width: 400,`.